# Prepare redux store when the app starts from a non-index page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

Simple SPA, a list of items, it will load from the API when `componentDidMount`. and store the result in the redux store

When the user clicks the list item, it will go to the item detail page, and display the detail from the redux store, a traditional from `container component` to `stateless component` pattern.

All works well, but one problem, when the user opens the web app right from the detail page `/item/:itemId`:

1. The server will return the `index.html`
2. `React router` will then take control and route the user to the detail page because the url matches.

The problem is, this time, the `store` is completely empty because of no initialization step.

What's the proper solution for this?

I think I can simply check the `props` in `componentDidMount`, if the desired `prop` is `undefined`, I will call API to do an initialization.

Or is there a way that I can do this step in the container component because it will know that the `redux store` is not ready before the `stateless component`.

Or consider the `list to detail` is such a pattern in the web world, is there a best practice for handling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar app once. Instead of fetching the state in the application, I had the fetching process + redux filling in parallel to the react app initialization.

So you would have one main Javascript file which will start the fetching, which when done, fills the redux storage. This will be async. So in parallel you can start the react app:

`fetchData().then(fillReduxStore());
ReactDom.render()`

So the react app will do all the routing and things it should do, and as soon as the data is there, the app will be filled.

Comment: I see, a very interesting approach, thanks for sharing. I have one question. When the user starts from the detail page, I want to simply grab the very item that the user requests rather than the whole list, but via this approach, it seems there is no way to distinguish from different cases, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You could check the url before fetching. If there is a Parameter or some /item/$id just extract it and fetch the data you need.

I think the key is to think of redux and react as two separate concerns, which you could handle separate :)

Comment: Understood. Yes, could simply check against `document.URL` to handle different cases. Will wait for other interesting solutions but this one sounds pretty nice because no change needed for the item detail page. Thanks.